# contract write function has no input data(0x)

Tags: transactions, eip-1559

I found this strange transaction that has no input data, when it is supposed to:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbc99dff4af801a8b8f06f1aa7679b4a24be73bdc09d58c6ae4eb23fb54015455

If u see the logs, it clearly has token transfers. So this must transaction is probably from some mint function and so it should have input data. Could someone explain whats happening with this transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a `receive` and `fallback` methods check [this](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2020/03/26/fallback-receive-split/) for more information about them and how to use them. Those are responsable for two scenarios:

- A contract received ether and no data.
- A contract received data, but no function matched the function called.

The target contract has such a `receive` function that is triggered when someone send ether with no data to the contract and this `receive` function calls the mint function to mint something based on its logic

```
receive() external payable {
    mint();
}
```

[image]

Comment: oh wow, I also just checked the contract and that makes total sense. Thanks!